# What is the gas cost of recovering a wallet address from a signature using Solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas-price, ecrecover

As titled. I understand that there's an ecrecover function in Solidity. Can I use it for recovering a wallet address from a signature? Is it cheaper than a Keccak hash operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public key recovery of an ECDSA signature uses the ECRECOVER operation and costs 3000 gas. If you have the public key you can derive the address and afaik a keccak operation(sha3) costs 30 gas.